# Selectively apply or suppress TypeScript error for implied `any` type (aka "--noImplicitAny")

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm half expecting there to be a special comment or option somewhere to selectively apply or suppress the TypeScript compiler option `--noImplicitAny` for some files / classes and that I just can't find information about it.

For context, I'm using `VS Code` and `tsc` installed via `npm`. I know about the `tsconfig.json` file and actually have it configured with `"noImplicitAny": true`

It works great, and it forces us to be specific about our types - the point of TypeScript after all. However, there are a few select scenarios where we are accepting in 3rd-party code that does not have the requisite explicit types, and are therefore tripping the compiler error.

We would like to suppress the compiler option / check for just those classes/functions/files without turning the option off globally in the `tsconfig.json`. Similarly to telling a linter to disable a certain rule with comments is what I'm hoping for.

Just splatting `<any>` casts or `: any` type information is not feasible as it's 3rd party and subject to updates.

Is there such an option / feature available?